# Configuration Visual Studio 2015 - Windows 10 Project

Tags: configuration, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I need to add a new configuration in Visual Studio 2015.
Exist other configurations and are correct & work.

When I had a new configuration, with name "Test", in option "Copy Settings from:" I selected "Empty" and I Check "Create  new project configuration".

If I run the application with this new configuration(For example Release, Debug, etc...) I have an error:

"Couldn't find the required information in the lock file. Make sure you have UAP,Version=v10.0.240/Win10- mentioned in your targets".

I dont know resolve this error.

Someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Im getting this error after installing npm packages for SASS and GULP

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
First, apparently, did you mean Visual Studio 2015? If not, you need to install VS2015.

In VS2015 that helped in my case - enable "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" in your project build properties and ensure that "Platform" not set to AnyCPU.

Comment: No. I resolve the problem. I put some "Flags" on properties of solution, on Debug Compiler and it's done. Thanks

Comment: Cold you please be a bit more specific of what you did to resolve this so it can help others?